# Search over all lines in the dictionary using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, search, filter, nspredicate, nsmutabledictionary

My data structure is:

[image]

Now I iterate through list and add "**Name**" string to `NSMutableArray` and then search and filter data using `NSPredicate`.

How can I search through my whole list? Through **Name** & **Address** strings in all arrays?

Filtering data:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [sectionsNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Loading data:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Load plist file
- (void)loadPList
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

      NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
        NSMutableArray *resultName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        sectionKeys = [NSMutableArray new];
        sectionsTitle = [NSMutableArray new];
        sectionsNames = [NSMutableArray new];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            NSMutableArray *annotationsToRemove = [ mapView.annotations mutableCopy ] ;
            [ annotationsToRemove removeObject:mapView.userLocation ] ;
            [ mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove ] ;

     ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Blue"];
                [resultArray addObject:@"Blue"];
                [resultDic setValue:ann forKey:@"Blue"];
                [sectionKeys addObject:@"Siwa"];


                for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) {


                    NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                    double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                    double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                    myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);
                    myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                    myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                    NSString *name = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                    [resultName addObject:name];

                    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
                    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];


                }

     self.tableData = resultDic;
            self.sectionsTitle = resultArray;
            self.sectionsNames = resultName;

            [myTable reloadData];


        });



    });


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your dictionary just contains arrays then you can loop over the keys in the dictionary and filter each individually (free written code):

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR Address CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                searchText,
                                searchText];

NSMutableArray *allMatches = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *key in myDictionary) {
    NSArray *array = [myDictionary objectForKey:key];

    NSArray *matches = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    if (matches.count > 0) {
        [allMatches addObjectsFromArray:matches];
    }
}
```

Doing this you also have access to the original key if you need it. And you finish with a list of all of the matches (an array of dictionaries which match).

Now in your table view you can return the number of rows as the count of all matches and get the `Name` and `Address` from the dictionaries to display.

Comment: Ok, that worked... but how I show my filtered result in my table? with Name in cell.textLabel.text and Address in cell.detailTextLabel.text? Big thanks!

Comment: Why it search only in last Array?

Comment: ? The code sample will search through all arrays stored in your dictionary. You will have to explain whatever problem you are having better.

Comment: I use your code sample and get search result only from last Array "Blue" - look at my data structure. Doesn't get result from "Yellow", "Purple", "Black" etc..

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", key); I get all Arrays, but for some reason didn't get result from other arrays

Comment: At the end of the loop try: NSLog(@"\n%@\n%@\n%@", key, matches, allMatches); What does the log say?

Comment: Ok.. was my inattention, it works now! Thank you! One question more. If I want search only through array's that was set ON in my settings, they are stored in NSMutableArray called "resultArray". I deleted loop and tried like this NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:resultArray]; but no success. NSLog(@"%@", resultArray); 2013-05-01 10:50:34.690 testApp[5078:907] (
    Green,
    Orange,
    Blue
)

Comment: Work like this NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Blue"]; but doesn't work with several

Comment: Probably best to post a new question with a full description and new code.

Comment: Ok, I started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315276/search-only-in-arrays-that-set-on-in-settings