# Search only in array's that set ON in settings

Tags: ios, search, filter, nsarray, nspredicate

I need to search and filter only in array's that set ON in settings.

Now I loop in `dict` for all array's:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR Address CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                    searchText,
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *akey in dict) {

        NSLog(@"%@", akey);

        NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:akey];

        NSArray *matches = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

        if (matches.count > 0) {
            [searchResults addObjectsFromArray:matches];
        }
    }
}
```

NSLog(@"%@", akey);

```
2013-05-01 11:34:07.256 testApp[5357:907] White
2013-05-01 11:34:07.262 testApp[5357:907] Yellow
2013-05-01 11:34:07.274 testApp[5357:907] Greenyellow
2013-05-01 11:34:07.275 testApp[5357:907] Darkblue
2013-05-01 11:34:07.277 testApp[5357:907] Green
2013-05-01 11:34:07.283 testApp[5357:907] Purple
2013-05-01 11:34:07.284 testApp[5357:907] Blue
2013-05-01 11:34:07.289 testApp[5357:907] Black
2013-05-01 11:34:07.291 testApp[5357:907] Red
2013-05-01 11:34:07.294 testApp[5357:907] Orange
2013-05-01 11:34:07.299 testApp[5357:907] BlueYellow
2013-05-01 11:34:07.305 testApp[5357:907] Brown
2013-05-01 11:34:07.308 testApp[5357:907] Rose
2013-05-01 11:34:07.312 testApp[5357:907] Gray
```

I have a `NSMutableArray` named `resultArray` which collect my array's that was set ON in settings

NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);

```
2013-05-01 11:40:46.917 testApp[5378:907] (
    Green,
    Orange,
    Blue
)
```

How to search only in `resultArray`? I tried:

`NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:resultArray];`

but without success.

This work only for one array:

```
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Blue"];
```

My data structure is:

[image: data structure]

Comment: this one totally confusing.

Comment: Now I have set on Green, Orange and Blue array's and I need to search only there, not from all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR Address CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                    searchText,
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *akey in dict) { 

        if ([resultsArray containsObject:aKey]) {

            NSArray *array = dict[akey];

            NSArray *matches = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

            if (matches.count > 0) {
                [searchResults addObjectsFromArray:matches];
            }

        }        

    }

}
```